# Merging 2 sorted files(with similar content) based on Timestamp in shellscript

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have 2 identical files with below content:

File1:

```
1,Abhi,Ban,20180921T09:09:01,EmpId1,SalaryX
4,Bbhi,Dan,20180922T09:09:03,EmpId2,SalaryY
7,Cbhi,Ean,20180923T09:09:05,EmpId3,SalaryZ
9,Dbhi,Fan,20180924T09:09:09,EmpId4,SalaryQ
```

File2:

```
11,Ebhi,Gan,20180922T09:09:02,EmpId5,SalaryA
12,Fbhi,Han,20180923T09:09:04,EmpId6,SalaryB
3,Gbhi,Ian,20180924T09:09:06,EmpId7,SalaryC
5,Hbhi,Jan,20180925T09:09:08,EmpId8,SalaryD
```

I want to append all File1's content in Files (based on the date in ascending order)

Outcome:

```
1,Abhi,Ban,20180921T09:09:01,EmpId1,SalaryX
11,Ebhi,Gan,20180922T09:09:02,EmpId5,SalaryA
4,Bbhi,Dan,20180922T09:09:03,EmpId2,SalaryY
12,Fbhi,Han,20180923T09:09:04,EmpId6,SalaryB
7,Cbhi,Ean,20180923T09:09:05,EmpId3,SalaryZ
3,Gbhi,Ian,20180924T09:09:06,EmpId7,SalaryC
9,Dbhi,Fan,20180924T09:09:09,EmpId4,SalaryQ
5,Hbhi,Jan,20180925T09:09:08,EmpId8,SalaryD
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please include the code you'd like help with. It's very difficult to debug code we can't see. Also, how does `sort -t, -k4 File1 File2` not achieve this for you?

Comment: @ghoti is right.. sort -t, -k4 works

Answer (score 2):

You can use below AWK construct to do this :-

```
awk -F "," 'NR==FNR{print $4, $0;next} NR>FNR{print $4, $0;}' f1.txt f2.txt | sort | awk '{print $2}'
```

Explanation :-

Prefix date column (`$4`) before every line (`$0`) for both the files.

`sort` it. And Then `print $2` which is whole line.

These printed lines will be in sorted order by date.

`f1.txt` and `f2.txt` are two file names.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following command

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next}{print a[FNR]"\n"$0}' file1 file2
```

with an array a store `file1`'s datas, `FNR` is `a`'s key.